Detrend 3D matrix with cdo
Is there a way to detrend a 3D data (lon, lat, time (62 years daily data during the summer season)) with cdo?
I know there is a command to do this for a time series, but i am not sure if i can use the same command which is
cdo detrend

for 3D data?
Actually, I tried to do it but what I get is a one time step file, instead of having the complete days during the 62 years
or is there a way to do it easily in python and get a .nc file with the detrended data?

It is the same command, are you sure you didn't type trend instead of detrend by mistake?
